# Using LAN-USB adapter to connect to internet telephony device

Tags: usb, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to create the following setup: I want to communicate to an internet phone adapter (a Linksys PAP2) from my computer. I can communicate with it fine when it's connected with LAN cable to the local network. However I now want to connect it directly to my computer using a LAN-USB adapter ([this one](http://laptopdriversnbc.blogspot.nl/2016/03/jp1082-usb-to-lan-driver-for-win-xp-win.html) or very similar).

Note that I'm not trying to get internet through the USB adapter or to supply internet to the phone adapter through the USB adapter, I just want to communicate with the phone adapter through the USB adapter. I want to keep access to the internet on my computer as it is.

When I make the connection (phone adapter - LAN cable - USB adapter - computer)  The device shows up in `ip link`:

```
7: enp0s16f1u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:53:44:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I can then do this:

```
ip link set enp0s16f1u1 up
ip addr add 192.168.99.1 dev enp0s16f1u1
ping 192.168.99.1
```

Which is successful, although I'm not sure whether the USB adapter is responding or (hopefully) the phone adapter behind it. Also I can't reach the adapter's configuration website at the IP, which was possible on the local network. I thought perhaps `dhcpcd enp0s16f1u1` could help, but this results in the following:

```
DUID 00:01:00:01:1c:44:4e:84:ac:9e:17:84:60:cf
enp0s16f1u1: IAID 4c:53:44:58
enp0s16f1u1: adding address fe80::31c0:b3d7:4414:b3b8
enp0s16f1u1: soliciting a DHCP lease
enp0s16f1u1: soliciting an IPv6 router
enp0s16f1u1: no IPv6 Routers available
timed out
dhcpcd exited
```

Via a telephone connected to the phone adapter, I can configure some options that might be helpful:

- Enable/disable DHCP (was enabled while trying `dhcpcd`)
- Set static IP address
- Set network/subnet mask
- Set static gateway IP

I've tried setting the static IP address to `192.168.99.1` and some ideas for the rest of the options, but wasn't sure what I should use. Perhaps some settings here or additional settings in `ip addr` could help? Or something else?

My computer is running Arch linux.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with the help from someone in the #archlinux IRC channel. My mistake was that I was trying to give `enp0s16f1u1` the same IP address/mask as the phone adapter. In the end the following did the trick:

```
ip link set enp0s16f1u1 up
ip addr add 10.0.0.5/24 dev enp0s16f1u1
```

I then set the phone adapter as follows:

- Disable DHCP
- Static IP address: 10.0.0.6
- Network/subnet mask: 255.255.255.0